# What is meant by "Cantor topology"?

Tags: general-topology

I would like to know what is meant by *Cantor topology*. Looking at Wikipedia, I was linked to this page [about Cantor space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_space)

Maybe I am no good reader (english is not my mother tongue) but where in this article is defined what the *Cantor topology* is?

Comment: This is an often used example. The Cantor set inherits its topology as a subset of the real line.

Comment: I've never heard the phrase "Cantor topology" before. What makes you think it means something? (The topology on the Cantor set is just the subspace topology as a subset of $\Bbb R$.)

Comment: For example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curtis%E2%80%93Hedlund%E2%80%93Lyndon_theorem the term Cantor topology is used in the last section of "Definitions".

Comment: I had the impression that "Cantor topology" somehow refers to the product- topology.

Comment: You point out a Wikipedia article whose opening is inconsistent, from a mathematical perspective.  On one hand it seems to say a topological space is a *Cantor space* iff it is homemorphic to the usual Cantor excluded-middle-thirds set, but on the other hand it applies the term Cantor space more generally to $D^S$ where $D$ is a finite set and $S$ may be any sort of nonempty index set whatsoever.  Obviously these cannot be homeomorphic when the cardinalities of $S$ differ from finite to countable, etc.

Comment: Regarding product topologies: With the discrete topology on $\{0,1\}$, the Cantor set is homeomorphic to the Tychonoff product-topology on $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}.$

Comment: @user254665 But this still holds for any finite set $A$ and its product topology as Alex S taught me. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Cantor topology or Cantor space is the unique perfect, compact, totally disconnected metric space. In other words, all metric space with those properties are homeomorphic to each other. The classic realization of the Cantor space is the middle-thirds Cantor set whose construction you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set). However, there are other ways to construct topological spaces which are homeomorphic to the middle-thirds Cantor set. For example, if $A$ is any finite set, the countable Cartesian product of $A$ with the product topology is the Cantor space.

Comment: unique up to homeomorphism*

Comment: (1.) That is, if we have, for example, a finite alphabet $A$ and consider the product topology on $A^{\mathbb{Z}}$, then this product topology is called the **Cantor topology**, i.e. *Cantor topology* is just another word for the product-topology? (2.) The product topology (or Cantor topology in other words) is, topologically the same, as the topology on the middle-thirds Cantor set which is just the subspace topology as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @mathfemi (1) Not quite. If $A$ were an infinite set, then $A^{\mathbb Z}$ with the product topology is not the Cantor topology, so you cannot say that the product topology and the Cantor topology are the same. (2) Yes, every space with the Cantor topology (which again, is not the same as the product topology) is topologically equivalent to the middle-thirds Cantor set.

Comment: How does $|A|$ not necessarily prime sit with the need for p-adic fields to be based on prime $p$? As these fields are homeomorphic to the Cantor set, and it looks like in this construction $A$ is the radix of the base $|A|$ representation.

Comment: @RobertFrost We need to separate the topological structure of the Cantor set from any topological properties we may choose to git it. THe $p$-adic field $\mathbb Q_p$ has different algebraic properties for each prime $p$, and is not defined for non-prime $p$, but the topological properties are all the same; they are all the Cantor set.

Comment: If we start a finite ring of non-prime order, and attempt to replicate the process of obtaining the $p$-adic field, I'm not quite sure what you would end up with topologically, but it may or may not have a natural topology which is the Cantor topology.

Comment: But be sure to keep separate in your mind an object's algebraic and topological structure.

Comment: @AlexS you end up with non-unique representations of numbers for $p\notin$ prime. So I guess the cartesian product of $A$ you defined also happens to be a locally compact field provided $|A|$ is prime.